# The C# project is targeting ".Net Framework, Version =v4.5",which is not installed on this machine

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on a C# project using VS 2012 installed on windows 8 this afternoon. It works well and I upload my code to TFS before I left for home.

But when I download and open this project using VS 2012 installed on windows 7. I got the error message below.

> The C# project is targeting ".Net Framework, Version =v4.5",which is
>   not installed on this machine. To proceed, select an option below.
>
> 1. Change the target to .Net Framework 4.5. You can change back to ".Net Framework, Version=v4.5" at later time.
> 2. Download the targeting pack for ".Net Framework, Version=v4.5". The project will not change.
> 3. Do not load the project.

I am sure I have installed .Net Framework 4.5 on my windows 7 laptop.
Now, I cannot load my project. Any one knows how to solve this problem?

Many thanks!

---------------  updates--------

For people who have the same problem:

I uninstalled VS 2012 and .Net Framework 4.5 and re install both of them. The problem is solved. Now I can load my project.

Comment: Also what you can do is just trying to uninstall vs2012 on you win 7 machine then re installing it again.

Comment: Hi RuneS. I read the FAQ before asking the question. Why this kind of question is not allowed?

Comment: Why not just try installing 4.5 again so you are certain instead of just sure...

Comment: @RuneS, am I missing something?  What is so horrible about this question?

Comment: @JusDaN, perhaps your English is not good, but "being sure" is a synonym for "certainty".  He could still be mistaken, but your editorializing his word choice is beyond useless.

Comment: @Kirk Woll: So just uninstalling and installing vs2012 again solved the problem as i stated... Also what is wrong about your question is that it is a bit unclear. And did not provide enough information about what is the real situation is, So it is considered ambiguous question.

Comment: @RuneS, nothing remotely ambiguous about the question.  This is made patently obvious by the fact you identified the problem and provided an answer within minutes of it being asked.

Comment: @KirkWoll : but the real problem ?! i just gave you the general fix...

Comment: unfortunetly this post was closed. It appears in my computer all the time too.

Comment: Note, this [SDKs and Downloads Page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/p/dotnet_sdks.aspx) doesn't load properly on IE9. So it's really confusing, try using another browser, and it should load the options. In my case I needed the 4.5.1 "Developer Pack".

Comment: Nothing wrong with this question and the one answer fixed it for me.

Comment: you should remove your edit and post it as an answer

Comment: The issue was not that 4.5 was not installed, it was that the 4.5.2 "[targeting pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42637)" was got uninstalled when you removed the old visual studio.

Answer (score 20):

Right-click your project and click in "Properties". In the tab "Application" see if you have the option for the 4.5 framework in the "Target Framework" dropdown list. If you have it, just select it and try to build your project again.
If you don't have this option, go to "Programs and Features" in Windows 7 and make sure you have .NET Framework 4.5 installed. If you have it, then try repairing your installation of VS 2012 in this same menu and verify again your options in the "Target Framework" dropdown list.

Comment: This fixed it for me on Windows 8 and VS 2013.

Comment: Which part of the answer fixed it?  The "repair" ?

Comment: Opening the project properties and selecting .NET Framework 4.5.2 fixed the issue for me. It seems that removing a separate edition of VS somehow removed the .NET Framework 4.5 target.

Comment: The part of the answer that helped me was a combo - first repairing the installation of VS 2012 and then change the "Target Framework" in the applications' properties.

Comment: I was sure to have had installed the .NET framework too, but it still complained! When I tried to install it - I got "**.NET Framework** 4.7.2 **or a later update is already installed on this computer**" dialog. The problem was I have installed the regular framework 4.7.2 - not the developer version.
The installation of the developer framework 4.7.2 worked and solved the problem, even the standard framework 4.7.2 was already installed.
After opening VS the framework 4.7.2 was selectable in the project properties.