# Visual Studio 2013 Net Framework Issues

Tags: .net-framework-version

I am trying to figure out how to fix Net Framework on Windows 8.1 computer.  When I open a project, this message is displayed.  When I try to install net frameworks, the system tells me that the framework is already installed.  Ran a DotNet Fix utility from Microsoft with no help. .Net 4.5 is built into the OS and higher versions comes with VS2013. So why is VS complaining.  Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found answer here on Stack Overflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/17607342/2028314

Also, remove Visual Studio and net framework and re-install them should work.

Comment: Win 7 and Win 8.1 are different.  Net Framework 4.5 is built into Win 8.1 and I believe it cannot be unintalled and installed again.  Also, last time I installed VS2013, it took a long time.  So trying to avoid uninstalling and installing again (unless I am sure this will fix the issue).

Comment: I have installed 4.5.1, then 4.5.2, then 4.5.3.  But VS 2013 fails to recognize any of those.  So it appears something amiss with overall Net Framework setup on this computer.

Comment: Did you try to install 4.5.0 ?